# split file into single lines via delimiter

Tags: perl

Hi I have the following file:

```
>101
ADFGLALAL
GHJGKGL
>102
ASKDDJKJS
KAKAKKKPP
>103
AKNCPFIGJ
SKSK
```

etc etc;

and I need it in the following format:

```
>101
ADFGLALALGHJGKGL
>102
ASKDDJKJSKAKAKKKPP
>103
AKNCPFIGJSKSK
```

how can I do this? perhaps a perl one liner?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -npe 'chomp if ($.!=1 && !s/^>/\n>/)' input
```

Remove the newline at the end (`chomp`) if there is no `>` at the beginning (`!s/^>/\n>/` is false). Also, add a newline at the beginning of the line if this is not the first line (`$.!=1`) and there is a `>` at the beginning of the line (`s/^>/\n>/`).

Comment: excellent. thank you so much. by the way - can you recommend a good perl book to learn?

Comment: @squiguy, look like there is http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do?green=30FBC471-1A8D-5D56-9F37-D67CB96C01EA&intcmp=af-mybuy-9780596004927.IP

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '
    if (/^>/) {print}
    else{
        if ($count) {
            print $string . $_;
            $count = 0;
        } else {
            $string = $_;
            $count++;
        }
    }
' file.txt
```